# How to add a css class to select option?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I am trying to add some **CSS classes** to specific options of my select.

It is no problem to add it to the select itself with the **attr**:

```
'attr'=>array('style'=>'width:300px', 'class'=>'class'),
```

But I want to add the class to the options itself:

```
<select name="select">
   <option class="x" value="1">red</option>
   <option value="2">blue</option>
   <option class="y" value="3">green</option>
</select>
```

I haven't found any way, yet. I investigated already the *ChoiceType* and the *ChoiceList* implementations.

My favorite way would be to add them on server side.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Do you want on selection of <option> it's value be the class name? please make me clear

Comment: No, he just wants to add custom classes to specific option items in the list.

Comment: @Gagan As Florian Peschka wrote I want to add a CSS class, no selection or similar.

Comment: @CSchulz : I have post the answer and let me know is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally the solution I am waiting for will be implemented in 2.7 ([source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12148)).

> choice_attr
>
> Returns the additional HTML attributes for choices. Can be an array, a
>   callable (like for "choice_label") or a property path. If an array,
>   the key of the "choices" array must be used as keys.

```
// array
$builder->add('attending', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
        'Maybe' => null,
    ),
    'flip_choices' => true,
    'choice_attr' => array(
        'Maybe' => array('class' => 'greyed-out'),
    ),
));
```

Comment: In Symfony 3, this still works, but it is interesting how it's given in the Docs: "This can be an array of attributes (**if they are the same for each choice**)"... so it seems like you could use one and the same entry in this array, for setting up a value for all choices. 

But then, 1 line lower it commands that "the keys of the choices array **must be used as keys**". I'd expect that - if you always want the same class for all choices - you could just use *'choice_attr' => ['class' => 'sameclass']*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for but as I understood via **[Florian Peschka's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741798/how-to-add-a-css-class-to-select-option/25967845#comments-25741798)** comment that you wanted to add `custom class` to specific(particular) option then here is what I tried..

**JQuery**

```
$('select>option:eq(1)').addClass("custom_class");
```

Here [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method : Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index. Just like `Array` it's index starts from `0` so if you wanted to select second option then write `eq(1)`.

In above code I have added `custom_class` to second option..

**HTML:**

```
<select name="select">
   <option class="x" value="1">red</option>
   <option value="2">blue</option>  # suppose you wanted to add custom class in this option
   <option class="y" value="3">green</option>
</select>
```

Which will now be looks like

```
<option class="custom_class" value="2">blue</option>
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaganGami/mqc4ytgL/1/)

To check in demo you can right click on drop-down and select `Inspect element with firebug`.
[image]

If this is not what you are looking for then please update your question with your Expected output..with description

Comment: Yes it is the expected output, but I hoped I can do it via templating or similar. :) But thanks so far.

Comment: @CSchulz : if it helpful then you can accept the answer and upvote.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the layout of specific widgets in your form . see the example [How can I add css classes to specific symfony2 form choices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770707/how-can-i-add-css-classes-to-specific-symfony2-form-choices)

Comment: Wouldn't this add the same class to every option?